# ANDROID - Display of Files on Android View

Tags: android, android-studio, dynamic, android-recyclerview

I have created a web portal on drupal from where users will upload files on the server.

Lets take for example after uploading files :

location of the file is :

```
website.com/userfiles/college/year/subject/file1.pdf
```

now I want to display this hierarchy in android App.

I want to display a List View / Recycler View which automatically gets the names of files in **subject** folder and display it dynamically.

*(If i add another file in the same folder on web, same gets automatically reflected in the app, one more entry of the file should come in the view)*

How can I do that?
I have no clue about it!

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You will need directory listing enabled on the remote server, and parse the HTML output in your app. (Or create an ex. Server side script (PHP?) that returns a directory listing)

Check out any of the availible http clients for Android, like third party OkHTTP, or LoopJ AsyncHTTPClient (I always liked his one) or HttpURLConnection which comes packed with Android.